# Ajax Query Dropdown not populating

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm very new to MVC and C# and I am trying to create a booking system so that when a user selects a Practice, Optician and Date a JSON query returns the available times.

My View Model:

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    [Display (Name = "Select Patient")]
    public Guid PatientId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PatientList { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Practice")]
    public Guid PracticeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PracticeList { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Optician")]
    public Guid OpticianId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OpticiansList { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Time")]
    public Guid TimeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimeList { get; set; }      
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        // Creates a new booking
        BookingViewModel bookingViewModel = new BookingViewModel();
        // Initilises Select List
        ConfigureCreateViewModel(bookingViewModel);

        return View(bookingViewModel);

    }

    // Initilises Select List 
    public void ConfigureCreateViewModel(BookingViewModel bookingViewModel)
    {
        // Displays Opticians Name 
        bookingViewModel.OpticiansList = db.Opticians.Select(o => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = o.OpticianId.ToString(),
            Text = o.User.FirstName
        });

        // Displays Patients name 
        bookingViewModel.PatientList = db.Patients.Select(p => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = p.PatientId.ToString(),
            Text = p.User.FirstName
        });

        // Displays Practice Name
        bookingViewModel.PracticeList = db.Practices.Select(p => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = p.PracticeId.ToString(),
            Text = p.PracticeName
        });

        // Displays Appointment Times 
        bookingViewModel.TimeList = db.Times.Select(t => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = t.TimeId.ToString(),
            Text = t.AppointmentTime
        });


    }


    // Allows Admin to create booking for patient 
    // POST: Bookings1/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(BookingViewModel bookingViewModel)
    {
        // to ensure date is in the future
        if (ModelState.IsValidField("Date") && DateTime.Now > bookingViewModel.Date)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Please enter a date in the future");
        }          

        // if model state is not valid
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Initilises Select lists
            ConfigureCreateViewModel(bookingViewModel);
            return View(bookingViewModel); // returns user to booking page

        }
        else // if model state is Valid
        {
            Booking booking = new Booking();
            // Sets isAvail to false
            booking.isAvail = false;
            booking.PracticeId = bookingViewModel.PracticeId;
            booking.OpticianId = bookingViewModel.OpticianId;
            booking.PatientId = bookingViewModel.PatientId;
            booking.Date = bookingViewModel.Date;
            booking.TimeId = bookingViewModel.TimeId;

            // Generates a new booking Id
            booking.BookingId = Guid.NewGuid();
            // Adds booking to database
            db.Bookings.Add(booking);
            // Saves changes to Database
            db.SaveChanges();
            // Redirects User to Booking Index
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

JSON Query to return Available times:

```
    // Json to return Availiable times
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AvailTimes(Guid practiceId, Guid opticianId, DateTime date )
    {
        var timesList = db.Bookings.Where(a => a.PracticeId == practiceId)
                                   .Where(a => a.OpticianId ==opticianId)
                                   .Where(a => a.Date == date)
                                   .Where(a => a.isAvail != false)
                                   .Select(a => new
        {
            Value = a.TimeId,
            Text = a.Time.AppointmentTime
        }).ToList();

        return Json(timesList);
    }
```

Ajax to populate times:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var times = $("#TimeId"); // Cache Time element
    times.prop("disabled", true);
    $("#PracticeId","#OpticianId","#Date").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("AvailTimes","Bookings")",
            type: "POST",
            data: { Id: $(this).val() }
        }).done(function (timesList) {
            console.log(timesList)
            times.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < timesList.length; i++) {
                times.append("<option value=" + timesList[i].Value + ">" + timesList[i].Text + "</option>");
            }
            times.prop("disabled", false);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

When a booking is made the IsAvail is set to false, therefore what I am trying to do with my JSON LINQ Query is return the tines that are available

However when I select a Practice, Optician and Date the Time is still disabled. I checked the console and am getting the following warning:

> The specified value '01/01/0001' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Select Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Select Date field is required." id="Date" name="Date" type="date" value="01/01/0001" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: @Heyyou Please see edit

Comment: The fact you have `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` on property `Date` and are using `EditorFor(m => m.Date)` suggests you are using the browsers HTML5 datepicker. If so you need to specify `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format). Note: do not use a `string` parameter as suggested below)

Comment: Also your ajax call is only posting back `data: { Id: $(this).val() }` and you don't even have a parameter named `Id` in the `AvailTimes()` method. All the parameters you do have will be `null` or the default

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are some problems in your code.

First:

> However when I select a Practice, Optician and Date the Time is still
>   disabled. I checked the console and am getting the following warning:

If the DateTime input is disabled (and empty), it means that you are sending a "null" datetime value to the controller. Since datetime cannot be null, it takes the default value, which is '0001/01/01'.

To solve this, you can use a nullable datetime parameter, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AvailTimes(Guid practiceId, Guid opticianId, DateTime? date )
{
    var timesList = db.Bookings
           .Where(a => a.PracticeId == practiceId &&
                  a.OpticianId ==opticianId &&)
                  a.isAvail != false &&);

     if (date.HasValue)
        timesList = timesList.Where(i => i.Date == date.Value);

    var final = timesList.Select(a => new
    {
        Value = a.TimeId,
        Text = a.Time.AppointmentTime
    }).ToList();

    return Json(final);
}
```

Second:

In your view, you are using a date in a different format than en-US culture.

en-US: MM/DD/YYYY

your format (usually used in South America): DD/MM/YYYY

If your server uses the en-US culture, which usually is the default, it might not recognize your date.

You have several choices. You can send your date as string and parse it using a specific culture. Like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AvailTimes(Guid practiceId, Guid opticianId, string date )
{
    var timesList = db.Bookings
           .Where(a => a.PracticeId == practiceId &&
                  a.OpticianId ==opticianId &&)
                  a.isAvail != false &&);

     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(date)) {
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo yourCulture =
         new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR"); //example
       DateTime yourDate = DateTime.Parse(date, yourCulture);
        timesList = timesList.Where(i => i.Date == yourDate);
     }

    var final = timesList.Select(a => new
    {
        Value = a.TimeId,
        Text = a.Time.AppointmentTime
    }).ToList();

    return Json(final);
}
```

Another way to accomplish this is to change the culture of the entire thread/or application. So, the MVC model binder will automatically recognize your date format, and no parse will be necessary.

There are others techniques you can use to handle date format in web application. If your application is accessed by only one culture, you probably won't have any problems. However, if your application is accessed by several cultures, I recommend you to read more about date time techniques on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I have tried both and I am still getting the following error `The specified value '01/01/0001' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.`

Comment: your input is sending that value to the controller. It either have to be null or a valid date. Remember to change the date parameter to a string.